# gVim can't view file created with Notepad in System32 folder

Tags: windows, vim

When I create a file called `hello.txt` in `C:\Windows\System32` with the text "hello" in it, `gVim` for some reason will not find this file. Can someone explain why this happens?

Here you can see I created the file in `Notepad`.
[image: Notepad]

Now I'm trying to find the same file in `gVim` using `:E`. `hello.txt` is nowhere to be found. `:e hello.txt` opens up a new file. I feel like I'm getting trolled by my computer.

[image: gVim]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a 32-bit Vim (both Bram's installer and the "Vim without Cream" installer often recommended are 32-bit) on a 64-bit Windows, then you've fallen victim to the WOW64 redirection in Windows. Since 32-bit applications are not compatible with 64-bit libraries, `C:\Windows\System32` when accessed from a 32-bit application actually gives you the content of `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

But don't despair, you can actually access the `C:\Windows\System32` on most 64-bit systems from within Vim, **you just need to use the special path `C:\Windows\Sysnative`** (which only seems accessible by 32-bit applications and maps to the 64-bit `C:\Windows\System32` directory).